# Set value of hidden field in Rails form with Javascript callbacks

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

Please i'll appreciate some help on this . 
I've got a view with 4 forms(created from iterating through an array of plans)  with a `plan_id` hidden field in each of them. I'm using `Stripe` custom integration, and i submit the specific form on Javascript callback, however the `plan_id` passed to my rails controller is ALWAYS the `plan_id` of the last form in the page

```
<% @plans.each.with_index do | plan,index | %>
 ...
<%= form_tag('/billings/subscription_checkout',:id => "elm-#{index}", 
    method: :post) do  %>
  <input name="plan_id" type="hidden" value="<%= plan.code %>">
  </input>

<a id="plan-<%= index %>" class="selectPlan" >Select Plan</a>
```

and then, i submit the form in a JS callback thus:

```
<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
key: "<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>",
image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
currency: 'usd',
token: function(token) {
 stripeToken = token.id;
 $("form#elm-<%= index%>").append($("<input type=\"hidden\" 
 name=\"stripeToken\" />").val(stripeToken));
 $("form#elm-<%= index%>").submit();
...
```

At the controller action, the value of `params[plan_id]` is always set to the value of the `plan_id` in the last of the forms and not the `plan_id` set in the form that was submitted.

If i however submit the form outside of the callback, i get the correct value in the hidden field.

Please how best can i handle this

Comment: Do you have multiple `<script>var handler = ...</script>` on the page? One for each form perhaps?

Comment: @muistooshort , I've got multiple `<script>var handler = ...</script>` on the page

Comment: You could try making separate `handler` variables in the JavaScript (`var handler<%= index %> = ...`). Or better (IMO), make just one handler that could work with any form, I'm not sure how Stripe checkout works though, I've only used Stripe for card processing.